# Managing multiple Flavours... exponential growth?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

Imagine a situation in which i need to have versions of my APK with or without ads, with or without CustomJarSDK and for three markets, GooglePlay, AmazonApps and SamsungApps.

In my perfect world it whould be only 7 flavours:

- With Ads
- Without Ads
- With CustomJarSDK
- Without CustomJarSDK
- For GooglePlay
- For AmazonStore
- For SamsungApps

And in my perfect world there whould be a way to combine flavours in gradle, for example:

- With Ads + SamsungApps + CustomJarSDK
- Without Ads + GooglePlay
- Etc...

Is that possible? or you are cursed and forzed to have all those flavours...?????

- For GooglePlay with ads
- For GooglePlay with ads and with CustomJarSDK
- For GooglePlay without ads
- For GooglePlay without ads and with CustomJarSDK
- For AmazonStore with ads
- For AmazonStore with ads and with CustomJarSDK
- For AmazonStore without ads
- For AmazonStore without ads and with CustomJarSDK
- For SamsungApps with ads
- For SamsungApps with ads and with CustomJarSDK
- For SamsungApps without ads
- For SamsungApps without ads and with CustomJarSDK

Comment: It depends. You can't merge flavors, but you can use folder resources to handle this case. For example you can define common src folders.

Comment: can you explain it a little more? whould be munch better if you can extend your comment in a response please

Comment: I added an answer. it is so simple to answer your question, it depends by your specific case. However you can find some tips to improve your structure to reduce the redundant parts.

Comment: Yep, I wish there was a way to specify valid flavors so it doesn't explode.  I'd like to either whitelist flavor combinations or exclude invalid ones.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult to answer your question. It depends by which resources are different in any flavor.

Currently **you can't extend** flavors or merge them.

However you can use use some tips to improve your project.

For example you can use **common sourceset resources** for different flavors.

Something like that:

```
+ App // module
|- src
   |- common // shared srcDir
      |- java
   + flavor1
      |- java
   + flavor2
      |- java
   + flavor3
   + flavor4
```

Then you can define somenthing like this:

```
 sourceSets {            
        flavor1.java.srcDir 'src/common/java'
        flavor2.java.srcDir 'src/common/java'
        flavor3.java.srcDir 'src/common/java'
    }
```

In your case you should evaluate if the flavors:

- For GooglePlay with ads
- For GooglePlay with ads and with CustomJarSDK
- For GooglePlay without ads
- For GooglePlay without ads and with CustomJarSDK

can use a common block:

```
 sourceSets {
            flavor1.java.srcDir = ['src/common/java', 'src/flavor1/java']
            flavor2.java.srcDir = ['src/common/java', 'src/flavor2/java']
            flavor3.java.srcDir = ['src/common/java', 'src/flavor3/java']
        }
```

Each **flavor can use the same sourceset defined in another flavor**.
Somenthing like that:

```
flavor2{
        java.srcDirs = sourceSets.flavor1.java.srcDirs
        res.srcDirs = sourceSets.flavor1.res.srcDirs
        resources.srcDirs = sourceSets.flavor1.resources.srcDirs
        aidl.srcDirs = sourceSets.flavor1.aidl.srcDirs
        renderscript.srcDirs = sourceSets.flavor1.renderscript.srcDirs
        assets.srcDirs = sourceSets.flavor1.assets.srcDirs
    }
```

Also **each flavor can define multiple resource folders**. For instance:

```
android.sourceSets {
   flavor1.res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', src/main/res2']
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that with that sample of code, i can't understand how to reuse the common code but adding the new code inherent from each flavour. Can you expand a little more your answer using the use case which i explained in my question?

Comment: Tryed to add more details , but as explained before it requires more details about your project

Comment: so, this will combine two source codes? flavor1.java.srcDir = ['src/common/java', 'src/flavor1/java'] I'm searching documentation or samples about this kind of combination and i can't find any samples about this. Did you tried it? Thanks

Comment: Yes I tried it. You can also add source with the `+=` annotation as  `main.java.srcDirs += '...'`. Of course if you specify a class in the flavor source you cannot specify it in the common folder.